# homepage is different from any other page on website

Tags: css, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Homepage loads differently than every other page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211562/homepage-loads-differently-than-every-other-page)

Why does my homepage have a width of 1024 px. And every page after that has a width of 1280 px? Even as full screen this is how it loads up. How why?

Specs: Browser : Chrome Pages located on local machine.

```
root { 
    display: block;
}
#leftcol a{text-decoration: none;}
#leftcol{   
    left: 10%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity:0.6;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
}
#left-placeholder{
    height: 100%;
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
}
#left-pusher{
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
.left-column-item{
    background: url('images/bgnav.jpg');
    height: 33.334%;
    background-size: 100%;
    opacity:0.6;
    color: white;
}
.left-column-item:hover{
    background: url('images/bgnav.jpg');
    height: 33.334%;
    background-size: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}
#content{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 5em;
    height: 100%;
    width: 70%;
    float:left;
}

body{
    background: url('images/background.jpg');
    background-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%}
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}
//html for homepage:

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <LINK href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type ="text/javascript">

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id ="leftcol">
                <a href="content/practice.html"><div class ="left-column-item">Practice!</div></a>
                <a href="content/AboutUs.html"><div class ="left-column-item">About Us!</div></a>
                <a href="content/contactUs.html"><div class ="left-column-item">Contact Us!</div></a>
            </div>
        <div id="left-placeholder"></div>
        <div id ="left-pusher"></div>
        <div id ="content">Math Practice Site<br>Welcome</div>
    </body>
</html>
// the practice page that is not loading correctly

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <LINK href="../styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <script type ="text/javascript">

            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <div id ="leftcol">
                    <a href="practice.html"><div class ="left-column-item">Practice!</div></a>
                    <a href="aboutUs.html"><div class ="left-column-item">About Us!</div></a>
                    <a href="contactUs.html"><div class ="left-column-item">Contact Us!</div></a>
                </div>
            <div id="left-placeholder"></div>
            <div id ="left-pusher"></div>
            <div id ="content">Math Practice Site <br> hello</div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: ... can you show link of homepage..?

Comment: Don't double-post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211562/homepage-loads-differently-than-every-other-page

Comment: why root{display: block;}? why not html{display: block;}?

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to understand your question.
Anyway, try to add the obligatory ";" after "width: 100%" in the "body" definition in your CSS file (just before "}")

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance makes me think the only real difference is the reference to the css page. Does the rest of the page have proper CSS applied to it, or is the CSS as a whole off?

If the latter, try replacing `../` with a full path?